# Can not set Language level to PHP 7.4 in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, settings, php-7.4

When I go to `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > PHP`:
There is no PHP 7.4 in "PHP language level", and the latest is PHP 7.3.
My version of PhpStorm is 2018.3.6

So how to debug why I don't see PHP 7.4? Or simply how to set PHP 7.4?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My version of PHPStorm is 2018.3.6

Upgrade your IDE to a newer version. PHP 7.4 support was added later (initial support in 2019.2 and proper one in 2019.3: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/2019-3/).

**P.S.** Latest PhpStorm is 2021.1.1 and it supports PHP 8.0

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/

Comment: How helpful is it to send someone off to  page that has over 80 points on it?

Comment: @TV-C-1-5 Which information are you missing? I believe this answer has enough information to answer that specific question (why 7.4 is not available in the Language Level drop box and what to do to have it there). The answer is "Upgrade the IDE to a newer version"

Answer (score 0):

You need to update to new version of PHP Storm.

The current version that I'm using is:

> PhpStorm 2020.2 Build #PS-202.6397.115, built on July 29, 2020

and supports version 7.4 and latest 8.0 for PHP Language Level pack.